# Report abuse Twilio Flex Whatsapp

Tags: twilio

When using Twilio Flex with Whatsapp, is there a way to report abuse? Or is there a way to block a phone number to prevent it from chatting with us?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything built into Flex to block numbers, but this is certainly something you could add yourself.

For a simple version, you'd need:

- somewhere (a database or other store) to store your block list
- a Twilio Function that can receive requests from Flex and add data to the block list
- a [Flex Plugin](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/plugins) that [adds a button to the task info panel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/tutorials/adding-components-flex-ui) that send the WhatsApp number to the Twilio Function above
- another Twilio Function that checks a WhatsApp number against the block list
- extra Twilio Studio widgets in your messaging flow that pass the incoming WhatsApp number to the Twilio Function that checks the block list and then check the response and if the number is blocked then end the conversation, otherwise pass the conversation on to a Flex agent

There are many ways of achieving this, but that's an outline how I'd build a simple version of this.